# Mostrar estilos CSS según if con php

Tags: php, css, if

Necesito que se muestren unos estilos específicos u otros, según la opción que elija el usuario. Si elige las opciones `A` o `B`, que muestre un `div` `(style="display: block")` y si es otra diferente que no lo muestre `(style="display: none")`.

**La cuestión es que no quiero repetir mucho código y quería saber si se puede hacer un if que condicione que sea "block" o "none" según corresponda.**

Quiero que sea una solución lo más sencilla posible y sin hoja de estilos externa.

Lo que tengo hasta el momento (funcional):

```
    <?php 
        if ($nombreTarifa == "A" || $nombreTarifa == "B") { 
    ?>
    <div class="caja" style="display: block;">
        <div class="showontarifa_2.0 showontarifa_2.1" rel="showontarifa_jform[prod_tarifa]" style="display: block;">
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->form->renderField('prod_potencia'); 

        // mucho más código irrelevante que he omitido

        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        } else {
    ?>
            //resto de tarifas que no sean A o B

        <div class="caja" style="display: block;">
             <div class="showontarifa_2.0 showontarifa_2.1" rel="showontarifa_jform[prod_tarifa]" style="display: none;">
             </div>
             <?php echo $this->form->renderField('prod_potencia'); 

             // mucho más código irrelevante que he omitido

             ?>
       </div>
       <?php } ?>
```

¿**Cómo puedo cambiar la propiedad CSS "display" mediante un** `if (style="display: block; o style="display: none;)` sin tener que repetir código?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con algo así:

```
<div class="caja" style="display: <?= (...condicion..) ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>;">
```

Es decir, usando el shorthand de condiciones de php.

Puedes ver otros ejemplos aquí:

https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples

Por último, verás que en vez de abrir bloque php y usar echo, en el ejemplo he usado `<?=` el short tag + echo de php.

Comment: Mas info sobre el [operador ternario aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 4):

Veo que la única linea que se diferencia es el `style="display: none;"` y `style="display: block;"` de la linea `<div class="showontarifa_2.0 showontarifa_2.1">`, así que podrías ocupar una condición ternaria:

```
<div class="caja" style="display: block;">
    <div class="showontarifa_2.0 showontarifa_2.1" rel="showontarifa_jform[prod_tarifa]" 
     <?php echo 'style="'.(($nombreTarifa == "A" || $nombreTarifa == "B") ? 'display: block;': 'display: none;' ).'"'; ?>>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('prod_potencia'); ?>
</div>
```

puedes consultar más acerca de [condiciones ternarias](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 2):

Otra manera pero esta vez sin usar estilos inline, ademas podes reusar estos estilos en otros lugares que lo necesites.

En tu archivo css agregas estos dos estilos:

```
.display-none{
    display:none;
}

.display-block{
    display:block;
}
```

Luego en tu php lo usas de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="caja <?= ($nombreTarifa == 'A' || $nombreTarifa == 'B')?'display-block':'display-none'; ?>">
```